# Researcher with the coworker relationship (spoilers)

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

The coworker relationship sticker states:

> Co workers: you may share knowledge as long as one if you is in the
>   correct city. (The researcher may give any card to their co worker for
>   one action)

My question is in regard to the researcher: **If the researcher is given coworker status with another character, can the researcher give any card to their coworker from any city**?

For example, if the scientist and the researcher are coworkers, and the researcher is currently in Milan and the scientist is in another city, can the researcher give the scientist the Tokyo card as an action on their turn? Could the researcher do this multiple times on their turn?

Comment: Please be careful with any spoiler content for a game like this - avoid putting it in the title and then label the title with "Spoiler" and/or use spoiler tags (>!) within your answer for any content from a packet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

Since the only restriction on the researcher giving cards is that they are in the same city if they get that relationship sticker they can give cards to the person they share it with at any time. This is a really useful combination that can be very powerful for the players.

In your example the researcher could to that and they can trade as many cards as they have actions with the co-worker.

Comment: In the example, when it is the scientists turn, can the scientist take ANY card from the researcher?

Comment: @Brainmaniac No, the card says the researcher may give for one action which does not include another person taking an action to take a card.

Comment: No it says pass

Comment: @Brainmaniac Look at what the text in the question says. It says for an action the researcher may give any card not that the coworker can take any card which leads me to read that part of the action can only take place on the researchers turn.

Comment: Aa kk see what u mean. I think the text is wrongly written in the post here. In our version of the game the text says: You may Share Knowledge with a co-worker as long as one of you is in the city of the card that is being passed. (The Researcher can pass any card)

Comment: @Brainmaniac I see, with that wording it does change my opinion as it does not appear at all to be dependent on the researcher taking action. As I don't have a copy I was not able to verify the wording on the card.

Comment: Ok tnx i Think so too.